# How to stop redundancy

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here is my little SQL table which contains sequels of movies:

```
CREATE TABLE "films" 
(
    "title" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "year" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "predecessor_title" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "predecessor_year" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "increase" NUMERIC NOT NULL
)
```

Here are some of my values:

```
Toy Story 2 1999 Toy Story 1995 28%    
Toy Story 3 2010 Toy Story 2 1999 69%
```

As you can see, it is somewhat redundant. Toy story 2 shows up both as a title and a predecessor. How can I create a table that doesn't have this?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Just any way for these not to be stored redundantly.

Comment: I can have multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
CREATE TABLE FILMS (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    TITLE TEXT NOT NULL,
    YEAR INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PREDECESSOR_ID INTEGER,
    INCREASE NUMERIC
)
```

ID is the primary key.

PREDECESSOR_ID is the ID of the predecessor movie. Can be null because the first movie of the series doesn't have a predecessor.

INCREASE is the increase. Can be null because the first movie doesn't have an increase.

Comment: Can I use the titles instead?

Comment: @lanardo No because they won't necessarily be unique. However, you can JOIN a table to itself or use WITH RECURSIVE to walk the `predecessor_id`s back until there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

When you design it using ORM (Hibernate) tool like this:

```
@Entity
public class Films{
@ID
@GeneratedValue
int id;

@NotNull
String titleText;

@NotNull
Integer year;

@JoinColumn
Film film;

Integer increase;

}
```

this looks cool. Here you can keep a reference of predecessor in `Film film;` No, matter if there is no predecessor. It would be null then.

Comment: The ORM option for SQLite is ORMLite if he wants to take a look: http://ormlite.com/